# How do I do a simple "select x where it's value of y is the max in z"?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How do I accomplish the following in the most efficient manner in SQL?

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELDN ... FROM TABLE1 WHERE FIELD1 = 
(the row with the max value from an aggregate query)
```

For example

```
SELECT * FROM PS_DEPT_TBL WHERE DEPTID =
...
SELECT DEPTID, COUNT(*) FROM PS_JOB GROUP BY DEPTID ORDER BY 2 DESC
(i'd want the row with the largest count above)
```

Comment: subquery or join I'm afraid.  and often not too efficiently.  Note: we'll want to know which DB you're using since it will affect the supported operations.

Comment: What database server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a literal answer to your question, see the below.

However, having knowledge of peoplesoft, I question what you're trying to do with that query, because ps_job contains effective dated rows. It will contain one row for every single change to an employee's job over time. The same employee might have 50 rows on it. So if you're trying to find the department with the most employees, this query is not correct. But as a literal answer to your question I think it does what you say you want.

```
select *
  from ps_dept_tbl
 where deptid in
       (select deptid
          from ps_job
         group by deptid
        having count(*) = (select max(num_recs)
                            from (select deptid, count(*) as num_recs
                                    from ps_job
                                   group by deptid)))
```

Comment: Yes, the above is a simplified version of the actual query I was running - this wouldn't make any sense as a peoplesoft query!

Answer (score 2):

Order the query by the value you want to min\max by, and use `LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1`(depends on your DB).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MAX()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) function to find the highest value from your aggregate query.

Comment: Actually, I think he's looking for an ID of "a" row with the maximum value in the aggregate in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the highest `DEPTID` using two subqueries

```
SELECT * 
FROM PS_DEPT_TBL 
WHERE DEPTID = (
    SELECT DEPTID
    FROM (
        SELECT DEPTID, COUNT(*) 
        FROM PS_JOB 
        GROUP BY DEPTID 
        ORDER BY 2 DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
)
```